# ExtJS 4 gridpanel in window annoying horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2

I am creating a grid in a window like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email',],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
title: 'BlaBla',
closable: true,
modal: true,
width: 800,
height: 460,
layout: 'fit',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        autoScroll: true,
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        title: 'Choose which features you would like to use to create parts.',
        // height: 300,
        columns: {
            items: [
                {
                    header: 'Name',
                    tooltip: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1
                }, 
                {
                    header: 'Email',
                    tooltip: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    },

]
}).show();
```

Which is generating a window like this:
[image: window with grid]

However, the gridpanel has an annoying horizontal scrollbar which is not necessary because the columns are fit.

Why is that scrollbar getting created and what should I use instead?

Comment: I dont see any scroll bar when I run your code in fiddle. @UDID: Even without changing any width, it looks good.

Comment: @Srikanth may be, but when I creating fiddle it is showing scrollbar so I assume this happen because of window width. If window is lesser than actual grid then this happen in general.

Answer (score 1):

This scroll bar is created because of width and height of window, Not because of grid. You please adjust the width of window and you will get desire results. I change `width` of window and coming perfectly. Here is your [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1k3c)

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign height & width to window, give it to your grid panel.
because of this window get auto height & width, simply depends on grid. ;)